# Pass values into Django form before form is made

Tags: python, django, forms

In my forms.py file, let's say I have something like this...

```python
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Model:
    model = Example
    fields = ['date_field']
    widgets = {
      'date_field' : SelectDateWidget(years=year_range(some_variable))
    }
    exclude = ()
```

If I wanted to put something into some_variable while the form is being created from and instance (`form = ExampleForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance_variable)`), how would one set a value to `some_variable` in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in the form's constructor:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        some_variable = kwargs.pop('some_variable')
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_field'].widget = SelectDateWidget(
                                                 years=year_range(some_variable))
```

And then create the form like this:

```
form = ExampleForm(request.POST or None,
                   instance=instance_variable,
                   some_variable=2015)
```